# how to embed qt-console with Ipython

Tags: ipython

Whenever I try to  use ipython with a qt as gui support it gives me this :

```
enter code here $ ipython --gui=qt
                  Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

 IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
 ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
 %quickref -> Quick reference.
 help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-   q      1DAvsew5j,guid=a3ed4bb7c5723eeff9aaed690000006e" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-  q1DAvsew5j,guid=a3ed4bb7c5723eeff9aaed690000006e" 
  Registered DEC:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true 
  Registered event listener change listener:  true
```

My questions are:

1. What is this and why won't it stop until the keyboard interrupt?
2. How do I embed a qt-console in ipython?

Comment: If you're trying to start the Qt console, the command is `ipython qtconsole`.

Answer (score 2):

This problem just started happening to me too. I am running Ubuntu 12.04. Removing a QT accessibility package (qt-at-spi) fixed this for me.

Here is the command to run from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge qt-at-spi
```

Source:
http://blog.koppi.me/2012/01/howto-fix-sni-qt19799-warn-024248-774-void-statusnotifieritemfactoryconnecttosnw-invalid-interface-to-snw_service-error-message-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Answer (score 0):

You can in theory accomplish the same thing (stopping the QT AT API messages) without purging the package by setting the environment variable QT_ACCESSIBILITY

i.e., add

```
export QT_ACCESSIBILITY=0
```

to your shell and/or system startup (like ~/.bashrc)

You can look at the README for the qt accessibility package here

/usr/share/doc/qt-at-spi/README